# Salvar informações em um SQLite e depois subir para um JSON com webserive

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, json, sqlite

Eu li vários tutoriais sobre como pegar um JSON e passar as informações para um SQlite, porém como eu faço o inverso, pego os dados da aplicaçao já salvos no SQLite e depois os transfiro para um webservice com o JSON... agradeço desde já

Comment: Isso depende com a linguagem que você vai utilizar..

Comment: O mais importante a se definir é QUANDO os dados vão sair do sqlite e ir para o banco externo através do webservice.
É no clicar de um botão? É sem o usuário saber? É quando o aplicativo abre? Dependendo da resposta, você terá uma abordagem diferente. 
Quanto a tecnologia: É recomendável usar uma biblioteca chamada Gson para transformar seu objeto em json. O webservice tem que ter uma classe identica a que você está enviando para que ele possa converter o json que chega na classe para, finalmente, realizar os inserts no banco externo.

Comment: Eu vou usar Java... quero q a aplicação faça sem o usuário saber, se ele estiver conectado ele atualiza se não nada muda no BD interno

Comment: Eu até já montei um BD interno usando SQLite, agora quero criar um webservice pra poder começar a passar as informações para a rede e deixar lá armazenado de forma online

Answer (score 2):

Adicione a dependencia do Gson do google ao seu gradle, tem no m2Repository, você vai fazer sua pesquisa no banco normal, transformar em um objeto java normal e então é só chamar o gson assim

```
new Gson().toJson(object).build();
```

Não me lembro exatamente se é assim, se for isso que você quer mesmo, recomendo dar uma olhada na documentação do Gson, é uma ótima classe, sempre uso, de tão simples eu nem lembro como faço...

Na documentação tem as anotações que você pode fazer nas suas classes para poder personalizar os json, levar ou não um campo e alterar o nome que ele vem no json...

https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Goals-for-Gson

Acredito que este link vai suprir as suas duvidas...